# Post a from with a MultipartFile using RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate, request-mapping

How do I post the following POJO to a `@PostMapping` using a `RestTemplate`

```
@Data
public class Form{
   private Long customMetaData;
   private String moreCustomMetaData;
   private Date evenMoreCustomMetaData;
   private MultipartFile file;
}
```

Which gets populated by

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name = "customMetaData" type="text">
  <input name = "moreCustomMetaData" type="text">
  <input name = "evenMoreCustomMetaData" type="text">
  <input name = "file" type="file">
</form>
```

which gets posted by

```
HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
HttpEntity<U> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(from, headers);

restTemplate.exchange(restUri + path, method, httpEntity, responseType);
```

to

```
 @PostMapping
 public ResponseEntity<Long> postForm(@RequestBody From form){
   return ResponseEntity.ok(-1L)
}
```

but I keep getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```